# How can i check Database Name with the help of JPA 1.5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How can i check Database Name with the help of JPA 1.5

I need to execute a native query based on the databse fetched out.

Comment: There is no such thing as "JPA 1.5". There is JPA 1.0, JPA 2.0, JPA 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Extend **JpaDaoSupport** class in your DAO class.

[JpaDaoSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/JpaDaoSupport.html) has method called **getJpaTemplate()** and that returns **JpaTemplate** object. Check this  JpaTemplate class and it's parent class - you can get database related details.